# Multipass mount: source is not readable

Tags: mount, multipass

I try to mount a directory to an multipass ubuntu instance. But I get the error:

`mount failed: source "<path_to_dir>" is not readable`

The directory should has the correct mode: `drwxrwxr-x@`

On macOS Catalina.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this as well.  Thankfully, it was just a matter of enabling *Full Disk Access* for `multipassd` in *Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy*.

[Image showing Security & Privacy and Full Disk Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8xhP.png)

Once I did that and then restarted Multipass (and the target VM), I was able to successfully `multipass mount` with no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has solved my problem.